# Configuration of a textfield with a related combobox - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, textbox

Good afternoon,

I'm working in ASP.NET.

I have a textbox where i need to insert manually some data, but that data is dependent on what is selected on a combobox.

So, to be easy to understand i give an example.

Combobox selected value "A" ---> Can only insert in textbox values "1,2,3,4,5"

Combobox selected value "B" ---> Can only insert in textbox values "6,7,8,9,10"

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

So here is the updated ASP code. Some thigns to note:

- I used VS Empty template (thus the ContentPlaceHolders) but the premise is the same.
- You will need to replace the name of the controls in the `Response.Write`s so they match your controls.
- You can remove the `<span>` and all references to it (`$('#text-valid')`...) in the javascript code if you don't want an error message.
- This uses a timer to validate the information. I saw this as the best method because if you select option b and try typing "10", it would fail on the 1. I have the delay set to 1 second (1000ms) but you can change this in the `setTimeout(...)`.
- I used jQuery for the sake of simplicity. This isn't a bad thing, just makes it more legible and cross-browser compatible.

So here it is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestingGround.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Grab the two fields we want to work with (don't forget to
            // change "combo" and "text" below to the name of your controls
            var fldCombo = '#<% Response.Write(combo.ClientID); %>';
            var fldText = '#<% Response.Write(text.ClientID); %>';

            // validation function to see if the current value is one of the values
            // specified in the combobox
            var isValidValue = function () {
                $('#text-valid').text('');
                var val = $(fldText).val();
                var range = $('option:selected', fldCombo).val().split(',');
                for (var r = 0; r < range.length; r++)
                    if (val == range[r])
                        return true;
                $('#text-valid').text('Invalid, must fall within: ' + range.join(', '));
                return false;
            };

            // does the actual validation of the field, or resets it to empty
            // and sets focus back in to it
            var validateField = function () {
                if (!isValidValue())
                    $(fldText).val('').focus();
            };

            // bind to the option (se we can validate the current value that's in
            // the textbox between changes
            $(fldCombo).change(function () {
                validateField();
            });

            // delay timer for validation on keypress
            var delayedValidate = null;

            // validate when the field changes (mostly on tabs or lose focus)
            $(fldText).change(function () {
                clearTimeout(delayedValidate);
                validateField();
            // also bind on a keypress (as they enter a value)
            }).bind('keypress', function () {
                delayedValidate = setTimeout(validateField, 1000); // allow you time to type in a valid number
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>TextBox content based on ComboBox</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Combo Box:</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="combo">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option A" Value="1,2,3,4,5" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option B" Value="6,7,8,9,10" />
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Box Value:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" /><span id="text-valid" style="text-indent:5px;color:red;"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a version with the ability to specify ranges. Also added a bit more robust checking (parsing the values to integer first before comparison):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestingGround.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var fldCombo = '#<% Response.Write(combo.ClientID); %>';
            var fldText = '#<% Response.Write(text.ClientID); %>';

            var isValidValue = function () {
                var val = parseInt($(fldText).val());

                if (val == null || isNaN(val))
                    return false;

                $('#text-valid').text('');

                var range = $('option:selected', fldCombo).val().split(',');
                for (var r = 0; r < range.length; r++) {
                    // is range[r] a numeric range
                    if (range[r].indexOf('-') != -1) {
                        var lowHigh = range[r].split('-');
                        var low = parseInt(lowHigh[0]), high = parseInt(lowHigh[1]);
                        if (val >= low && val <= high)
                            return true;
                    }
                    // range[r] is just a straight number
                    var match = parseInt(range[r]);
                    if (val == match)
                        return true;
                }
                $('#text-valid').text('Invalid, must fall within: ' + range.join(', '));
                return false;
            };
            var validateField = function () {
                if (!isValidValue())
                    $(fldText).val('').focus();
            };

            $(fldCombo).change(function () {
                validateField();
            });
            var delayedValidate = null;
            $(fldText).change(function () {
                clearTimeout(delayedValidate);
                validateField();
            }).bind('keypress', function () {
                delayedValidate = setTimeout(validateField, 1000); // allow you time to type in a valid number
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>TextBox content based on ComboBox</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Combo Box:</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="combo">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option A" Value="1-3,4,5,11-99" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option B" Value="6,7-9,10" />
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Box Value:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" /><span id="text-valid" style="text-indent:5px;color:red;"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I think what the OP means is that if option `A` is selected only the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (individually) should be accepted as input in the textbox.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the value in the textbox is to be inserted manually from that range of values.

Comment: Yea, hit submit prematurely (fat fingered it). I'll still post a solution in case someone else needs it, but looks like you had it under control.

Comment: I still need a solution, so if you can help me, i appreciate it.

Comment: @FelipeCosta: Working on it now. ;-)

Comment: @FelipeCosta: Are you okay with a jQuery solution (having trouble across browser)? otherwise, I can do it in pure ASP, but you'll either be stuck with UpdatePanels or PostBacks (I assume you want a seamless experience).

Comment: @FelipeCosta: My apologies for the delay, but I've updated my answer. See if that suites your needs.

Comment: Excelent Brad! Just what i need! :) Yes, i can use jquery, no problem! Thank you! Just one more question, if you don't mind.. is it possible to have the values of the dropdown in a range, ie, if the range is [1,10] the values that are valid are 1,2,3,...,9,10; or [1,10] and all valid are 1,1.25,1.50,...,9.50,10. I hope I've made myself understood.

Comment: @FelipeCosta: New version accepts ranges (see bottom code block). ;-)

Comment: Thank you again Brad. With all your help i have what i need. I hope that when you need help i can be so good as your giving the solution. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS AJAX extensions.  There is an extension for textbox controls (FilteredTextBox Extender) that only allows certain characters to be entered.  You can use that, and when the combobox's selected value changes you can modify which numbers are allowed by the extension from code-behind.